# Logistic Regression: How to know if we lack of predictors?

Tags: logistic

In the variable selection, we only have the different methods for excluding the explanatory variables. But after all, how can we know if we need to search for a new predictor to add into the model or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you an example for easy practical checking, which also works for other binary classification algos.

Lets say you have enough data and split it into "training" and "testing".
Then I would just suggest you plot the ROC curves for the training and the test to get the AUCs. Usually the AUC of the trainingset should be better then the testingset AUC (If it is a big difference, then you should check for overfitting).

If your AUCs in general are relatively low, this could mean you haven't enough data or you haven't all the necessary predictors. To check which issue matters you should train models from 10% of the training data, 20%, 30% etc. till 100%.

- If the performance goes up all the time, then u need more data
- if it doesn't go up with more data, then you should think about new variables.

Edit: If it is more a problem of variable selection, then I would suggest a combination of forward and backward selection.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much for the answer, I totally agree with you!